# Issue while sharing semaphore objects between process in parallel python

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, parallel-python

I am facing issue while passsing any semaphore objects or synchronizing objects like Events, pipes , queues etc to a child process when used with parallel python
I am getting following error when i passed a Queue to child process.
 ' **through inheritance' % type(self).__name__
RuntimeError: Queue objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance**

No issue was seeen when i used a multiprocessing library

```
import pp
import time
from multiprocessing import Event, Queue, Manager, Pool

e = Queue()

def startt() :
    e.put(1)
    return 1


ppservers = ()
# Creates jobserver with automatically detected number of workers        
jobServer = pp.Server(ppservers=ppservers,proto=2)
#submit the work to the job pool or job server
job = jobServer.submit(startt,(e,),(),("time", ), globals = globals())
res = job()
print e.get()
print res
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're having this issue because you're passing the queue object when you submit the job:

```
job = jobServer.submit(startt,(e,),(),("time", ), globals = globals())
#                              ^ here
```

Two things to note:

1. The queue is already global. You don't need to pass it as an argument.
2. You *can* pass the queue as an argument if you use a [multiprocessing.Manager](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.sharedctypes.multiprocessing.Manager):

```
manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
shared_queue = manager.Queue() # this shared queue can be passed as an argument
```

The call to `manager.Queue()` will actually return a proxy to the queue rather than the queue itself, and the manager process will handle all of the synchronization necessary in the background.

Comment: i tried with manager but i am getting authentication error , but no authkey is provided in my program. Following is the error messgae

Comment: File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 435, in answer_challenge
    raise AuthenticationError('digest sent was rejected')
multiprocessing.AuthenticationError: (AuthenticationError('digest sent was rejected',), <function RebuildProxy at 0x02C81070>, (<function AutoProxy at 0x02C81BF0>, Token(typeid='Queue', address='\\\\.\\pipe\\pyc-7364-1-gupzzw', id='2ae3bc0'), 'pickle', {'exposed': ('empty', 'full', 'get', 'get_nowait', 'join', 'put', 'put_nowait', 'qsize', 'task_done')}))

Comment: @user2088083 Tracebacks are very difficult to understand in comments. It would be better to post your follow-up as a new question. I haven't seen that kind of authentication error, so I don't think I can help much. Posting it as a new question will get it more visibility.